# Totals after filtering Pandas Pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I created a pivot table in pandas and after that, I filtered one of the rows, so far so good, however, the Grand total in the filtered table still contains the filtered values, How can I update the total values not to include the filtered amounts? Thanks

```
SBKCF = pd.pivot_table(CF, index = ['Cash Flow','Type'],
                 values = ['2,017','2,018','2,019','2,020'],\
                 aggfunc = np.sum,
                 margins = True)
SBKCF
Filtered = SBKCF.query('Type != ["Loan Inflow"]')
```

Comment: IMHO, you should do your filtering before your pivot in this case.

Comment: You are certainly right, it works, thanks mate, clearly you know why more than I. !!